# Where do I get Windows 7 drivers for my Bose Soundlink Bluetooth speakers?

Tags: windows, audio, bluetooth

I've successfully paired my speakers with my Windows 7 computer, but they're not working.  Device Manager shows two unknown Bluetooth devices, and can't find drivers for them.  I couldn't find any drivers on the Bose website either.

Where do I get these drivers?

Comment: Please post the make and specific model of PC so others can find this solution when searching.

Comment: @Moab: my research suggests that the problem is common to many different makes and models.  Besides, the problem only occurs when someone mistakenly thinks the missing drivers are associated with the Bluetooth device, so they'd not be likely to search for their PC make and model.  (At least, I certainly didn't - my search terms were all along the lines of "Bose Soundlink Windows drivers".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing drivers are for Bluetooth, not for the Bose Soundlink speakers specifically.

Installing the latest Bluetooth software for my machine (in my case, the [Dell Wireless 380 Bluetooth Application](http://www.dell.com/support/home/nz/en/nzdhs1/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=9CP1N&fileId=3292921010&osCode=W764&productCode=latitude-6430u-ultrabook&languageCode=en&categoryId=NI)) resolved the problem.

Comment: Thank you! That driver installation link helped! Though, I had to restart my PC twice because it worked.